# CMake generation problem with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: cmake

Using `cmake` from command line, I got:

```
"== Building Windows-Release =="
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
```

Where `CMakeError.log` contain:

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 31/12/2018 12:54:05.
Project "C:\myproj\CMakeFiles\3.13.1\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
Creating directory "Debug\".
Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
Creating "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue CMakeCCompilerId.c
CMakeCCompilerId.c
c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'CMakeCCompilerId.c': No such file or directory [C:\myproj\CMakeFiles\3.13.1\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\myproj\CMakeFiles\3.13.1\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\myproj\CMakeFiles\3.13.1\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(ClCompile target) -> 
c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'CMakeCCompilerId.c': No such file or directory [C:\myproj\CMakeFiles\3.13.1\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.43
...
```

I tried repairing the installation of Visual Studio, and renstalling CMake, but nothing seems to work it. Also looked at similar thread here, but nothing was helpful.

Comment: Does the file `C:\myproj\CMakeFiles\3.13.1\CompilerIdC\CMakeCCompilerId.c` exist?  It should be located along side `C:\myproj\CMakeFiles\3.13.1\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj`.  Does this happen all projects or just this one?  Also I normally see the line `-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 6.1.7601.` but that seems to be missing.  Is there anything on the command line for `cmake` that is out of ordinary?

Comment: It does exists. It happens in all the `cmake` projects. I installed Windows 10 SDK regardless of Visual Studio but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: This is pretty strange. Maybe it's a weird file permissions problem with having the build folder in C:\. You can try opening `C:\myproj\CMakeFiles\3.13.1\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj` directly in Visual Studio and see if the IDE can read the file and compile it. Also, If you use Visual Studio create project template in this folder does that work? Maybe its Visual Studio that isn't working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I met the exact same question with you. After a very very long struggle, I finally find the solution for me. I am not sure whether that is the same problem you met, but I still want to write and recode this strange problem.

Firstly, I also reinstall cmake, repair the VS and add many components in it and fixed(brake) many PATH environments, but all of them don't work, and I bet the problem is not because of these problems.

As the two messages:

- The C compiler identification is unknown
- The CXX compiler identification is unknown

They do not exactly mean the cmake don't detect the VS compiler, it just means that the cmake's use it to build its demo but fail. And from the errorlog, I even can believe your VS has already installed success and work well. The only problem is that the compiler can't open the 'CMakeCCompilerId.c' file.

I don't know whether have your check the .c file is exactly in the project location, but it is in there very well in my computer (otherwise, it means that the cmake failed to create this file, and maybe you need to open it as an administration)
I am very confused about why the compiler can't read that and try to directly open the .vcxproj file in VS and change many settings but still get the same error, like below.

[image: pic1]

After some try, I move the project to the desktop and reopen it, then it builds success! So as the whole cmake project. I am also be shocked by that.

[image: pic2]

After some compare and research, I found error reason in me, I am using the git in windows-wsl to clone the project to my windows file system(it has a little risk to break the file permission in wsl), it works well in normal, but as a cmake cross-compilation, I guess it may use some linux-like way to operate files and therefore meet some file permission problem.

So, the final solution to me is using the git in cmd or download the whole project in the browser instead of using the git in wsl. (Truly a little funny-. and may differ with your situation)

Hope these can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for my problem turned out to be that case sensitivity was turned on in the current directory.

Turn off case sensitivity or switch to another directory.